# hadoop streaming workflow multiple files

Tags: hadoop, awk, mapreduce

I am trying to write a workflow with hadoop streaming action which executes a awk program, Below is my scenario

Hadoop streaming commands works fine from client.However ever when executing as oozie workflow  it does not work as its not able to find second file. please note the awk script is on local home directory which is mounted on hadoop as well and the input paths are on HDFS
In sample.awk(code attached below)  i am passing two variables $1 and $2 which should get data from file1 and file2

### From CLI  , I have also attached the streaming workflow which I configured from hue which is not working as expected.

```html
/usr/bin/hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-2.3.0-mr1-cdh5.1.0.jar -D mapreduce.job.reduces=0 -D mapred.reduce.tasks=0 -input /user/cloudera/input/file1 /user/cloudera/input/file2 -output /user/cloudera/awk/ouput -mapper /home/cloudera/diff_files/op_code/sample.awk -file /home/cloudera/diff_files/op_code/sample.awk
```

```
Workflow.xml
------------------


<workflow-app name="awk" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
  <global>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name></name>
                    <value></value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
  </global>
    <start to="awk-streaming"/>
    <action name="awk-streaming" cred="">
        <map-reduce>
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <streaming>
                <mapper>/home/clouderasample.awk</mapper>
                <reducer>/home/clouderasample.awk</reducer>
            </streaming>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.output.dir</name>
                    <value>/user/cloudera/awk/output</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>oozie.use.system.libpath</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.input.dir</name>
                    <value>/user/cloudera/awk/input</value>
                </property>
                </configuration>
            <file>/user/cloudera/awk/input/file1#file1</file>
            <file>/user/cloudera/awk/input/file2#file2</file>
        </map-reduce>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="kill"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

Kindly see this link for more details
http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/JobConfFile

```
<property>
<name>mapred.input.dir</name>
<value>/user/cloudera/awk/input/file1,/user/cloudera/awk/input/file2</value>
<description>A comma separated list of input directories.</description>
</property>
```